# Creating 6to4 setup for home

Tags: ipv6, 6to4

I have Verizon FiOS at and there is no word on when they will implement native IPv6 support. I need to use IPv6 at home.

I do have a few VPS machines that have IPv6

Do I need any special router at home in order to implement 6to4?

Also what are the limitations to using 6to4?

Comment: 6to4 is a deprecated protocol. Expect connectivity issues. Using a 6in4 tunnel from a provider like Hurricane Electric is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not too difficult to set up 6to4 yourself, I would recommend using a router that does it automatically.  Recent versions of [LEDE](https://lede-project.org/) and OpenWRT come with a package `6to4` that does all the necessary setup, as well as with a deamon `odhcpd` which will announce the resulting IPv6 prefixes to all of your hosts.  See [the OpenWRT documentation](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network#protocol_6to4_ipv6-in-ipv4_tunnel) for more information.

Note that 6to4 is a deprecated protocol, and you will find it slow and unreliable due to the lack of public 6to4 relays.  A better choice would be to use a tunnel broker, e.g. the one [provided by Hurricane Electric](https://tunnelbroker.net/).  Again, this is best [set up using LEDE or OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/network#protocol_6in4_ipv6-in-ipv4_tunnel).